# What features do you wish were in common languages?

Tags: language-features

What features do you wish were in common languages? More precisely, I mean features which generally don't exist at all but would be nice to see, rather than, "I wish dynamic typing was popular."

Answer (score 11):

I've often thought that "observable" would make a great field modifier (like public, private, static, etc.)

```
GameState {
   observable int CurrentScore;
}
```

Then, other classes could declare an observer of that property:

```
ScoreDisplay {
   observe GameState.CurrentScore(int oldValue, int newValue) {
      ...do stuff...
   }
}
```

The compiler would wrap all access to the CurrentScore property with notification code, and observers would be notified immediately upon the value's modification.

Sure you can do the same thing in most programming languages with event listeners and property change handlers, but it's a huge pain in the ass and requires a lot of piecemeal plumbing, especially if you're not the author of the class whose values you want to observe. In which case, you usually have to write a wrapper subclass, delegating all operations to the original object and sending change events from mutator methods. Why can't the compiler generate all that dumb boilerplate code?

Comment: Sounds a lot like the AspectOriented approach which is at the moment hyped (more or less).

I think the drawback will be, that the result will be very hard to debug (because of the side hidden side effect, similar problem with operator overloading in C++)

Comment: The way I've conceived of it, the observer always gets an immutable instance of the old/new values. So I don't think it'd be nearly as problematic for debugging as it might seem.

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty good idea. I wonder if I could do it in Ruby?

Comment: zarawesome: Probably.  It sounds like something you could do with a metaclass, which is what we called AOP's functionality before it needed a cool acronym.  :-)

Comment: Clojure does this by default - you can basically "add-watch" to any reference and get a notification with the old and new value whenever it changes

Answer (score 5):

I guess the most obvious answer is Lisp-like macros.  Being able to process your code with your code is wonderfully "meta" and allows some pretty impressive features to be developed from (almost) scratch.

A close second is double or multiple-dispatch in languages like C++.  I would love it if polymorphism could extend to the parameters of a virtual function.

Answer (score 5):

I'd love for more languages to have a type system like Haskell. Haskell utilizes a really awesome [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) system, so you almost never have to *declare* types, yet it's still a strongly typed language.

I also really like the way you declare new types in Haskell. I think it's a lot nicer than, e.g., object-oriented systems. For example, to declare a binary tree in Haskell, I could do something like:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Nothing
```

So the composite data types are more like algebraic types than objects. I think it makes reasoning about the program a lot easier.

Plus, mixing in type classes is a lot nicer. A type class is just a set of classes that a type implements -- sort of like an interface in a language like Java, but more like a mixin in a language like Ruby, I guess. It's kind of cool.

Ideally, I'd like to see a language like Python, but with data types and type classes like Haskell instead of objects.

Comment: A nice bit of abstraction, but I wonder if it wouldn't allow for some fun debugging nightmares to arise...

Comment: What sort of debugging nightmares?

Comment: I don't think it would cause debugging nightmares.  This type of syntax is to a great extent merely syntactic sugar for structs.

Comment: If you like type inference, check out objects and polymorphic variants in OCaml.

Comment: People have [worked](http://www.python.org/workshops/2000-01/proceedings/papers/aycock/aycock.html) with Python type inference, so it can be done - I think that something like `import typecheck` and a `@typed` decorator would be ideal, such that it could be used for testing purposes and then disabled later.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of closures / anonymous functions.

```
my $y = "world"; 

my $x = sub {  print @_ , $y }; 

&$x( 'hello' );  #helloworld
```

and

```
my $adder = sub {
    my $reg = $_[0];
    my $result = {};
    return sub { return $reg + $_[0]; }
};

print $adder->(4)->(3);
```

I just wish they were more commonplace.

Answer (score 4):

Things from Lisp I miss in other languages:

- Multiple return values
- required, keyword, optional, and rest parameters (freely mixable) for functions
- functions as first class objects (becoming more common nowadays)
- tail call optimization
- macros that operate on the language, not on the text
- consistent syntax

Comment: Multiple return values suck. Get tuples.

Comment: @Jon Harrop:  You can return something like tuples in any language.  Multiple return values are something (almost) completely different.  For one, you get a single, unboxed, "innocent" value if you do just a standard one-value-bind of the return values, but you can also do a multiple-value-bind.  Also, the values can be kept in multiple registers instead of writing them out to RAM---I have not seen semantics for such a thing outside of assembly yet.

Comment: No, multiple return values are nothing more than a special case of tuples. Tuples don't have to be allocated. In HLVM, tuples are always unboxed.

Comment: @Jon Harrop:  If you return `(tuple x y z)` from your function, and your caller called that function as providing a single value, e.g. `(let ((a (foo h k))) #| ... |#)`, which value does `a` contain then?

Comment: @Svante: Then `a` contains the value `(tuple x y z)` but that says nothing about the representation in the compiled code.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: With multiple values, i.e. when you return `(values x y z)`, `a` contains the value of `x`.  So you see, these concepts are orthogonal.  Multiple values are primarily something like optional additional return values, which do not get in the way when you need just the first.  For example, you can do `(let ((f (floor a b))) #|...|#)` to get a rounded value, but you can also do `(multiple-value-bind (f r) (floor a b) #|...|#)` to also get the remainder.

Comment: @Svante: Extracting the first element from a tuple is hardly a concept orthogonal to tuples themselves.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: it is not extracted, it is just there.  The point is that you do not need to think about the additional return values unless you need them.  Multiple values are a concept of function call semantics, while tuples are a concept of container semantics.

Comment: @Svante: Now you're projecting limitations specific to Lisp. Objectively, there is no reason for any of this to have anything specifically to do with function call semantics. Multiple values are just another kind of container. One that is almost identical to tuples...

Comment: @Jon Harrop:  You are confusing semantics with implementation details.  A car is not the same as driving.  It does not make sense to say "Driving sucks.  Use cars instead."

Comment: @Svante: "You are confusing semantics with implementation details". That is impossible in the absence of defined semantics or an implementation. I have been talking abstractly about the concept. You have a specific implementation in mind that does not do this. There is a disconnect but it exists only in your mind. There is no need to draw this artificial distinction between tuples and multiple values...

Comment: @Jon Harrop:  One could perhaps say that "multiple values are the application of tuple techniques to function return mechanisms", but that still misses the semantic point described above (which would not make any sense if you just look at the tuple technique).  This distinction is as artificial as the distinction between "driving" and "car".

Answer (score 2):

To start things off, I wish the standard for strings was to use a prefix if you wanted to use escape codes, rather than their use being the default.  E.g. in C# you can prefix with @ for a raw string.  Similarly, Python has the r prefix.  I'd rather use @/r when I don't want a raw string and need escape codes.

Answer (score 2):

More powerful templates that are actually *designed* to be used for metaprogramming, rather than C++ templates that are really designed for relatively simple generics and are Turing-complete almost by accident.  The D programming language has these, but it's not very mainstream yet.

Comment: Check out MetaOCaml too.

Answer (score 2):

`immutable` keyword. Yes, you can make immutable objects, but that's lot pain in most of the languages.

```
class JustAClass 
{
    private int readonly id;   
    private MyClass readonly obj;
    public MyClass 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently it seems `JustAClass` is an immutable class. But that's not the case. Because another object hold the same reference, can modify the `obj` object.

So it's better to introduce new `immutable` keyword. When `immutable` is used that object will be treated immutable.

Comment: Some support for immutability would be helpful, but I'm not quite clear what an `immutable` keyword should do.  Could you clarify?

Comment: If `immutable` keyword is used in variable declaration, then the referenced object will be immutable, that means referencing variable can't change that object as well as no other referencing variable. Just like value types in C#.

Comment: What would be the effect of copying the reference variable, or a field or property of it, somewhere else?  There are a lot of corner cases to deal with.  Also, there's a big difference between a "read-only" reference and an "immutable" one.  Code which holds a read-only reference cannot modify the target, but has no assurance that the target won't be modified by something else.

Comment: If you copy that variable somewhere else another copy of that object will be created, just like value type in C#. And that's why I'm proposing `immutable` keyword.

Comment: Presently, copying a struct simply produces a bit-for-bit copy of anything the struct contains, including object references.  It sounds like you're proposing having the copy-struct operator produce a deep copy.  That would require changing some fundamental aspects of how .net works.  I would like to see more support for value-based programming, but working such a thing into the existing framework could be tricky.  A few things that would help would be the ability to declare (non-virtual) instance members as being callable on `null` (the methods would check whether `this` was null and...

Comment: ...act accordingly (though the unfortunate `struct` constraint on `Nullable<T>` would then be a nuisance), a means of specifying whether `this` and other parameters should be passed unconditonally by ref, value, const-ref/value (for struct/class types), ref/value (for struct/class types), or unconditionally by value, and a covariant `IReadableArray<out T>` interface which each `System.Array` would implement for its type.  Also a means of having properties expose value types by ref (so something like `foo.PropertyOfTypePoint.X += 5` would work).

Comment: When you create `struct`, it will always be immutable. And one of the reasons, we don't use `struct` that much, because of performance issue related to immutability. So I'm proposing  when `immutable` keyword is used with variable declaration. Only object that is referenced by this immutable variable will be immutable. When object is referenced by another variable, a copy of immutable object will be created. And that object will be treated like other mutable object unlees that other variable is immutable. So you are only making an object immutable when you think it's necessary.

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence.  Structs inherit the mutability of the locations in which they are stored.  If a struct in a mutable location is passed by `ref` to a method, that method can mutate the struct directly in its original storage location, with no copying required.  Are you referring to the way that struct members receive `this` by reference, except when applied to read-only values?  I will say that .net suffers from the lack of a `const ref` parameter convention, but I don't know if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: @user "Only object that is referenced by this immutable variable will be immutable". Your English is wrong here but, if I guess what you mean, your meaning is also wrong. Structs are not always mutable and even immutable structs can refer to mutable objects.

Comment: @JonHarrop "even immutable structs can refer to mutable objects." Yes, that's my point. Immutable struct can refer to mutable objects and struct itself doesn't ensure immutability of referred objects. So when a variable is declared with `immutable` keyword, that object and the entire closure of objects that object directly or indirectly refer will be immutable

Answer (score 1):

I like some of the array manipulation capabilities found in the Ruby language. I wish we had some of that built into .Net and Java. Of course, you can always create such a library, but it would be nice not to have to do that!

Also, static indexers are awesome when you need them.

Comment: Did you mean to post this comment on someone else's post? I never said anything about F#.

Comment: Err, yeah. No idea where though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Type inference.  It's slowly making it's way into the mainstream languages but it's still not good enough.  F# is the gold standard here

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was a self-reversing assignment operator, which rolled back when out of scope.  This would be to replace:

```
type datafoobak = item.datafoobak
item.datafoobak = 'tootle'
item.handledata()
item.datafoobak = datafoobak
```

with this

```
item.datafoobar @=@ 'tootle'
item.handledata()
```

One could explicitely rollback such changes, but they'd roll back once out of scope, too.  This kind of feature would be a bit error prone, maybe, but it would also make for much cleaner code in some cases.  Some sort of shallow clone might be a more effective way to do this:

```
itemclone = item.shallowclone
itemclone.datafoobak='tootle'
itemclone.handledata()
```

However, shallow clones might have issues if their functions modified their internal data...though so would reversible assignments.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see single-method and single-operator interfaces:

```
interface Addable<T> --> HasOperator( T = T + T)

interface Splittable<T> --> HasMethod( T[] = T.Split(T) )
```

...or something like that...

I envision it as being a typesafe implementation of duck-typing. The interfaces wouldn't be guarantees provided by the original class author. They'd be assertions made by a consumer of a third-party API, to provide limited type-safety in cases where the original authors hadn't anticipated.

(A good example of this in practice would be the INumeric interface that people have been clamboring for in C# since the dawn of time.)

In a duck-typed language like Ruby, you can call any method you want, and you won't know until runtime whether the operation is supported, because the method might not exist.

I'd like to be able to make small guarantees about type safety, so that I can polymorphically call methods on heterogeneous objects, as long as all of those objects have the method or operator that I want to invoke.

And I should be able to verify the existence of the methods/operators I want to call at compile time. Waiting until runtime is for suckers :o)

Comment: see haskell type classes

Comment: and scala's structural types.

Comment: and objects in OCaml, IO, Go...

Answer (score 0):

Lisp style macros.

Multiple dispatch.

Tail call optimization.

First class continuations.

Answer (score 0):

Call me silly, but I don't think every feature belongs in every language. It's the "jack of all trades, master of none" syndrome. I like having a variety of tools available, each one of which is the best it can be for a particular task.

Comment: Yeah, but then integration of all these sub-projects in a million different languages is a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

Functional functions, like map, flatMap, foldLeft, foldRight, and so on. Type system like scala (builder-safety). Making the compilers remove high-level libraries at compile time, while still having them if you run in "interpreted" or "less-compiled" mode (speed... sometimes you need it).

Answer (score 0):

There are several good answers here, but i will add some:

1 - The ability to get a string representation for the current and caller code, so that i could output a variable name and its value easily, or print the name of the current class, function or a stack trace at any time.

2 - Pipes would be nice too. This feature is common in shells, but uncommon in other types of languages.

3 - The ability to delegate any number of methods to another class easily. This looks like inheritance, but even in the presence of inheritance, once in a while we need some kind of wrapper or stub which cannot be implemented as a child class, and forwarding all methods requires a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like a language that was much more restrictive and was designed around producing good, maintainable code without any trickiness.  Also, it should be designed to give the compiler the ability to check as much as possible at compile time.

Start with a newish VM based heavily OO language.

- Remove complexities like Operator Overloading and multiple inheritance if they exist.
- Force all non-final variables to Private.
- Members should default to "Final" but should have a "Variable" tag to override it. (This may require built-in support for the builder pattern to be fully effective).
- Variables should not allow a "Null" value by default, but variables and parameters should have a "nullable" tag that indicates that null is acceptable for that variable.

It would also be nice to be able to avoid some common questionable patterns:

- Some built-in way to simplify IOC/DI to eliminate singletons,
- Java--eliminate checked exceptions so people stop putting in empty catches.

Finally focus on code readability:

- Named Parameters
- Remove the ability to create methods more than, say, 100 lines long.
- Add some complexity analysis to help detect complicated methods and classes.

I'm sure I haven't named 1/10 of the items possible, but basically I'm talking about something that compiles to the same bytecode as C# or Java, but is so restrictive that a programmer can hardly help but write good code.

And yes, I know there are lint-type tools that will do some of this, but I've never seen them on any project I've worked on (and they wouldn't physically run on the code I'm working on now, for instance) so they aren't being very helpful, and I would love to see a compile actually *fail* when you type in a 101 line method...

Comment: If you are a PHB and your programmers are that incompetent that you don't trust them with some flexibility, the better answer is to fire them and get new ones.

Comment: I'm not a PHB, I'm a programmer who's spent 20 years fixing other programmer's cute tricks.  And I tend to be called in when a company has screwed up their stuff pretty bad.

Comment: You don't need restriction, you need declarative languages.